# Designing a bluetooth audio unit for speaker

Tags: amplifier, bluetooth, speakers, impedance-matching, sound

(Cross posting from Sound design stack exchange since it was declared off topic there)

I have a sony speaker from an old Home Theatre System that is broken now leaving the standalone speakers in a good unused condition. I'm trying to design a Bluetooth capable audio unit to convert this into a nice Bluetooth speaker for my room. I need some help selecting the components for this project. Attached is an image of my speaker.

[image]

1. How can I find the rated power of this speaker as I'm unable to find a proper datasheet or document on the internet that gives me this value. Is there a way to experimentally find out the power requirement of a speaker?
2. The rated impedance is 3 Ω. I've found some amplifier modules (like [PAM8430](https://sensorembedded.com/index.php?main_page=product_info&cPath=13_47&products_id=562)) on the internet but the specifications say that it can support 4 Ω and 8 Ω speakers can I still interface 3 Ω speakers and expect decent performance? Or is there a way I can increase the impedance of this speaker by adding some resistors etc or do I have to search for an amplifier that supports 3-ohm speakers?
3. This speaker has +ve and =ve pins, can I directly connect these to the different parts of a 35mm TRS headphone jack or is some other kind of interfacing required?

Comment: 1) You could look at how many watts the amplifier this was connected to can output to this speaker. 2) You can raise the impedance by putting a resistor in series, but that also means speaker is driven with much higher impedance. There is also a chance that 4 ohm capable amps can drive this 3 ohm speaker. 3)  In general 3.5mm TRS connectors are not used for speaker connections, because it is too easy to connect something else to it instead of a speaker and have it damaged. Use connectors and terminals normally used for speakers, obviously.  4) Basically asking what to buy is off topic here.

Comment: @Justme the amplifier previously driving this speaker was a part of a big home theatre setup and I don't think I can measure that. I guess I'll just try to drive it with the 4 ohm amplifier and see what happens

Comment: Removed the product recommendation sub-question. These are off-topic here.

Comment: Maybe you could point me to certain prominent websites where I can search for amplifiers based on their Impedance ratings?

Answer (score 2):

> Is there a way to experimentally find out the power requirement of a speaker?

That's less of a required than a maximum values. Go higher than that, and you damage the speaker; that's an easy experiment, but not very useful to you, unless you have spare speakers...

> The rated impedance is 3 Ω … can support 4 Ω and 8 Ω speakers

Well, that's what ratings are for: to tell you what they promise will work. So, no, from that product page alone, this won't work.

It might be helpful to actually google for the PAM8430and find the original [data sheet](https://www.diodes.com/assets/Datasheets/PAM8403.pdf) of the amplifier IC: It also doesn't specify operability at 3Ω. What it does say, however, is that the thing won't output more than 3W. Pretty certain a speaker your speaker's size can withstand that.

Also, a home theater speaker won't be very loud when driven with <= 3W. So, really not the amplifier you're looking for. This thing is designed to drive built-in laptop speakers and phone speakers. (datasheet, first page!)

It also specifies things for 10% THD and 1% THD only: This is *not* a Hifi component. So,

> Or is there a way I can increase the impedance of this speaker by adding some resistors etc or do I have to search for an amplifier that supports 3-ohm speakers?

I'd recommend looking into better amplifiers, anyway, since you seem to be concerned with sound quality.

> This speaker has +ve and =ve pins, can I directly connect these to the different parts of a 35mm TRS headphone jack or is some other kind of interfacing required?

Not quite sure what you mean here. TRS headphone jacks are not a sensible way to attach a large speaker to an amplifier: they are not designed for the high currents speakers can work with.

Comment: Well, there was a **35** mm TRS mentioned.  I expect it could carry more current than a standard 3.5mm TRS - if you can find a place to buy one.  :)

Comment: @JRE ah, good ole 35mm headphone jack, which can also double as explosive fuse holder, if you happen to have spare anti-aircraft ammunition. :D